# Using getValue method for map in java of type <String,Integer>

Tags: java, maps, typecasting-operator, getvalue

When executing the following section, an error is coming in the `getValue()` method. I tried passing s as an argument inside `getValue()`. Doesn't work there too.

```
//Mymap<String,Integer>()       
while(in.hasNext()){
    //in is a scanner object
    String s = in.next();
    // Write code here
    //s is a string to be searched
    if (Mymap.containsKey(s)) {
        //the value corresponding to s is to be retrieved
        Integer i= (Integer)Mymap.getValue();
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(s+"="+Mymap.get(s));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Mymap`? `getValue` doesn't exist in the interface `Map`, it only exists in `Map.Entry`

Comment: What do you mean by iterating on the EntrySet @Rouliboy

Comment: getValue makes no sense on the Map interface, it does not exist. Iterate over EntrySet if you need to. If you want to get the value of a specific key, use `Map.get(s)`. But I do not understand what you try to do with getValue

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as others pointed out, the method `getValue()` **doesn't exist**, hence the compilation error.

[Here is the list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#method.summary) of all methods of the HashMap class.

If you want the integer value that correspond to the key `s` and store it in `i`, you should call `Mymap.get(s)` ... like you did in the line:

```
System.out.println(s+"="+Mymap.get(s));
```